# permutation importance in h2o random Forest

Tags: random-forest, h2o

The CRAN implementation of random forests offers both variable importance measures: the Gini importance as well as the widely used **permutation importance** defined as

> For classification, it is the increase in percent of times a case is
>   OOB and misclassified when the variable is permuted. For regression,
>   it is the average increase in squared OOB residuals when the variable
>   is permuted

By default *h2o.varimp()* computes only the former. Is there really no option in h2o to get the alternative measure out of a random forest model?

Thanks!
ML

Answer (score 1):

H2O does not calculate permutation importance. Please see the [documentation](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/drf.html#faq) for the explanation of how variable importance is calculated.

For your convenience I'll paste it as well below:

***How is variable importance calculated for DRF?***

*Variable importance is determined by calculating the relative influence of each variable: whether that variable was selected during splitting in the tree building process and how much the squared error (over all trees) improved as a result.*

A feature request has been previously made for this issue, you can follow it [here](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4027) (though note it is currently open).

Comment: Thanks, the answer is both useful and surprising since the Gini importance has been shown to suffer from enormous bias in the presence of catgeorical variables

Comment: See this post (https://blog.hwr-berlin.de/codeandstats/variable-importance-in-random-forests/) for an example on the perils of Gini importance.

Comment: May I ask if it is possible to obtain the oob indices for the individual trees in the h2o forests? That would enable me to write my own permutation importance function.